# Codeigniter method in controller does not call method in model

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I need your help..
In my view file I use ajax to request data to my controller.
Here is the ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#selCat').change(function(){
       var id = $(this).val(); // selected name from dropdown #table
       $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>'+'index.php/client/ajax_subcat',  // or "resources/ajax_call" - url to fetch the next dropdown
        async: false,
        type: "POST",     // post
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: "html",    // return type
        success: function(data) {  // callback function
         $('#selSubCat').html(data);
        }
       })
      });
     });
    </script>
```

Meanwhile the ajax_subcat() function in client controller is like this :

```
public function ajax_subcat(){
    //  $this->load->view('content/ajax_subcat');

        if($_POST){

            $catcode = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);
            $result = $this->preference_model->getSubCategory3($catcode);
            //$result = $this->preference_model->getSubCategory2();
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$catcode');</script>";
            //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$result->cat2name_EN');</script>";

            foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo $row->cat3name_EN;
            # code...
            }
        }

        //$this->load->view('content/');
    }
}
```

As you can see in the controller, I tried to call the function getSubCategory3($catcode); in my model but this line was not executed. I tried to use alert to see what happened.

because the first three echos were executed, I got the alert. But it seems the code stopped when encountered

```
    $result = $this->preference_model->getSubCategory3($catcode);
```

and then returned nothing to the view.

the function in my preference_model is like this :

```
function getSubCategory3($cat2code){
        $return = array();
        $queryString = "SELECT id, cat3code, cat3name_EN FROM `subcategory` WHERE cat2code = '".$cat2code."' ORDER by cat3name_EN";
        echo $queryString;

        $query = $this->db->query($queryString);

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                array_push($return, $row);
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Nothing was executed in preference_model.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code ?

Note :

I loaded the model in the function __construct() of my client controller

```
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('preference_model');
    }
```

When I changed the echo alert in the controller to echo a string, nothing is printed on my screen.

Comment: is it a preference_model or reference_model

Comment: $this->load->model('Model_name'); did you setup the model ?

Comment: It's preference_model and I have loaded it in my controller. I have edited my question with more detail

Comment: Instead of using `alert` in `model` you can check with `echo` and `print_r`

Comment: This is really strange. I tried as you suggested to change the alert with print_r and echo and nothing is printed now

Comment: Why you want alert in model ???

Comment: I just wanted to see whether it goes into my model or not but it doesn't

Comment: Is your class and file named preference_model ?

Answer (score 0):

In `Codeigniter` we need to load the `Models`, `Helpers` and `Libraries` before using them.

Add the line below in your code before calling the model method

```
$this->load->model('preference_model');
```

You can also make the alternate name to use in your code

```
$this->load->model('preference_model', 'prefrence');
$result = $this->preference->getSubCategory3($catcode);
```

Comment: I actually loaded in function __construct() but still encountering the problem I wrote here.

Comment: Write your __construct method and the preference_model code

Comment: I added it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem.
It turned out I should not echo any other thing but the result that I want to pass back to the caller. fiuhhh

Here is my final ajax_subcat() code

```
public function ajax_subcat(){

        if($_POST){
            $catcode = $this->input->POST('id',TRUE);
            //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$catcode');</script>";
            $result = $this->preference->getSubCategory3($catcode);
            //$result = $this->preference_model->getSubCategory2();
            //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$catcode');</script>";
            //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$result->cat2name_EN');</script>";
            $output = null;
            foreach ($result as $row) {

             $output .= "<option value='".$row->cat3code."'>".$row->cat3name_EN."</option>";
        }

         echo $output;
        }

        //$this->load->view('content/');
    }
```

My second drop down menu is successfully populated now.

Thanks everyone for your helps!